# Access Violation Exception when launching the native webbrowser from the app

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows, windows-8.1

In my WinRT App in C#, I have a userControl for the settings which contains a webview that open a local html file. I intercept the link on this html file with javascript code to launch the native webbrowser. When I do that, the native webbrowser display the link correctly but my application crash at the same time with an 'access violation' exception.

Here is the code for my UserControl :

```
public sealed partial class SimpleSettingsNarrow : UserControl
{
    public SimpleSettingsNarrow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ConditionWB_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ConditionWB.ScriptNotify += ConditionWB_ScriptNotify;
        ConditionWB.AllowedScriptNotifyUris = WebView.AnyScriptNotifyUri;
        ConditionWB.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Assets/testWebview.html"));
    }
    private async void ConditionWB_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {  
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(e.Value));
    }

}
```

And here is the xaml code :

```
<UserControl
x:Class="MyNameSpace.SimpleSettingsNarrow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyNameSpace"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="768"
d:DesignWidth="692">
<UserControl.Resources>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0">
    <Grid Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <!-- Root grid definition -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Header area for panel -->
        <Grid Background="White" Grid.Row="0">

            <Grid Margin="40,32,17,13">

                <Grid.Transitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="50" />
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Grid.Transitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="24.6667" Text="Déclaration de confidentialité" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />



            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,20,0,20" Padding="0,0,20,0">
            <WebView x:Name="ConditionWB" Loaded="ConditionWB_Loaded_1"></WebView>

        </ScrollViewer>


    </Grid>
</Border>
</UserControl>
```

And the testWebview.html file contains :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xml:lang="fr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 test
 <a href="javascript:window.external.notify('http://www.google.fr')">google</a>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Do you have any ideas why it crashes like this ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using Windows 8.1.

In Windows 8.1 AllowedScriptNotifyUris usage is not allowed instead enter the URL in "Content URIs" in project "Package.appxmanifest".

Note: give URL must be "https" (http will not work).